# My code for a LocalBinaryPatern in python is running very slow. Any tips?

Tags: python, performance

My code for a LocalBinaryPatern in python is running very slow. I tried optimizing it with tips from online. I'am still getting used to python, and programming in General so any tips are very welcome! Here is the code:

```
def localbinarypattern(image, radius=2):
    h, w = image.shape
    if radius == 1:
        return 0
    else:
        abase = math.pi/4
        xshift, yshift = [0 for _ in range(8)], [0 for _ in range(8)]

        for i in range(8):
            xshift[i] = - radius * sin(i*abase)
            yshift[i] = radius * cos(i*abase)

        feat = [0 for _ in range(255)]
        lbp = [0 for _ in range(8)]
        base = [1, 2, 4,8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
        for y in (range(radius, (h-radius))):
            for x in (range(radius, (w-radius))):
                lbp = [0 for _ in range(8)]
                for i in range(8):
                    cx = xshift[i]+x
                    cy = yshift[i]+y
                    ry = int(cy+0.5)
                    rx = int(cx + 0.5)

                    if image[ry][rx] > 0:
                        lbp[i] = 1
                
                bits = 0
                for i in range(8):
                    bits += int(lbp[i]*base[i])

                if bits < 255:
                    feat[bits] += 1

        sum_lbp = 0
        for i in range(len(feat)):
            sum_lbp += feat[i]
        if sum_lbp ==0:
            print ("warning: the sum of LBP feature is zero!\n")
        else:
            for i in range(len(feat)):
                feat[i] /= sum_lbp
        return feat
```

Comment: small tip: `feat = [0 for _ in range(255)]` => `feat = [0]*255`

Comment: also `sum_lbp = 0
        for i in range(len(feat)):
            sum_lbp += feat[i]` => `sum_lbp = sum(feat)`

Comment: but this question seems best suited for codereview

Comment: Thanks had not heard of codereview! beter check it out thanks for the tips though!

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Can you please add your imports, currently it is unclear if e.g. `sin` is from `math` or `numpy`. If you could also add some example in-/output, then answering this question would get a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

## No `else` after `return`

You have code like

```
if x:
    return 0
else:
    ...
```

Just drop the `else`, because you previously already returned. Use else branches only if the code converges again after the two branches, not if you exit the function (`raise`, `return` or `exit()`).

## Double Initialization

You have code creating two lists:

```
        xshift, yshift = [0 for _ in range(8)], [0 for _ in range(8)]

        for i in range(8):
            xshift[i] = - radius * sin(i*abase)
            yshift[i] = radius * cos(i*abase)
```

You can combine those:

```
xshift = [-radius * sin(i * abase) for i in range(8)]
xshift = [ radius * cos(i * abase) for i in range(8)]
```

## Further Dead Code

- Initialization of `h, w` at the beginning can be moved down, after checking the radius.
- `lbp = [0 for _ in range(8)]` -- you're doing that once before the loop and then in every iteration.

## C-isms in Loop Iteration

It looks like you're used to writing in C (or a similar language) where you can only access an array by index. It shows e.g. in this code:

```
sum_lbp = 0
for i in range(len(feat)):
    sum_lbp += feat[i]
```

In Python, you would write this loop like this instead:

```
sum_lbp = 0
for value in feat:
    sum_lbp += value
```

An additional minor improvement specific to this case is to write it in one line:

```
sum_lbp = sum(feat)
```

Get familiar with the tools Python gives you at hand, they can make your life easier. In this case it's just the `sum()` function, but also you're not making use of e.g. dictionaries, which could make this code cleaner.

## Redundant Parentheses

Here are two redundant pairs of partheses:

```
for x in (range(radius, (w-radius))):
```

Same code without them:

```
for x in range(radius, w - radius):
```

## Redundant Type Conversions

Looking at `int(lbp[i]*base[i])`, I wonder why you `int()` the product. Both only contain integers, as far as I can tell.

## Off-by-one Error

This code looks suspicious:

```
feat = [0 for _ in range(255)]
...
bits = 0
for i in range(8):
    bits += int(lbp[i]*base[i])

if bits < 255:
    feat[bits] += 1
```

Since an octet can take 256 different values, I'd expect `feat` to have 256 values as well. That way you could eliminate the `bits < 255` check. Another way to simplify this is to reuse the `sum()` function again. Also, `base[i]` is `1 << i` and `lbp[i]` is either zero or one, so you can also write this `lbp[i] << i` eliminating `base` entirely.

## Further Redundant Code

Look at the inner loop:

```
# init `lbp` with zeroes
lbp = [0 for _ in range(8)]
# actually fill `lbp`
for i in range(8):
    ...
    if image[ry][rx] > 0:
        lbp[i] = 1
# compute values from `lbp`                
bits = 0
for i in range(8):
    bits += int(lbp[i]*base[i])
```

This uses too many temporaries. Instead, try this approach:

```
bits = 0
for i in range(8):
    ...
    if image[ry][rx] > 0:
        bits += 1 << i
```